# Login Page not loading code from file PHP/codeigniter/Bootstrap

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a review site with code igniter in which you're able to login and add reviews. I've made a navigation bar with the Home and Login navs. I've created a login file and linked it to the navigation bar however once I click on login page there's a blank page and when i inspect the code there's no code within the body even though there's clear code in the file.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">  
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <title> Login </title>

            <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel ="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>application/css/homestyle.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>application/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!-- These classes only work if you attach Bootstrap. -->
            <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-white bg-grey">   
                <h2 > GAMES REVIEW </h2>
                <!-- Home -->
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php">Home</a>
                <!--  Login  -->
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>application/views/login.php">Login</a>
            </nav>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Login Form -->
            <div class="login col-md-4 mx auto text-center" id="login">
                <h1> Login </h1>
                <form method="post" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
        <!-- Load in the required scripts -->
    </html>
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow , check your PHP version  and you have all extensions that CI require

Answer (score 0):

```
href="echo base_url() application/css/homestyle.css"
```

tries to open document like this http://localhost/sitename/application/css.......
but it's not supposed to parsed with any controller.
i suggest you to use CDN instead.

you ca also use FCPATH const to address to your file like this

```
(FCPATH.'application/folder/file');
```